# Как добавить mouseover в javascript для всех тегов li в которых находиться div который при наведение на li должен появляться?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как добавить mouseover в javascript для всех тегов li в которых находиться div который при наведение на li должен появляться?
Вот быстрый пример html:

```
    <ul class="one">
     <li class="two">
      <div class="three"></div>
     </li>
     <li class="two">
      <div class="three"></div>
     </li>
     <li class="two">
      <div class="three"></div>
     </li>
     <li class="two">
      <div class="three"></div>
     </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation

Comment: `li:hover div { display: block }` — это делается одной строчкой CSS. Если цель не в обучении JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.two');

divs.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
    el.querySelector('.three').classList.toggle('block')
  })
})
```

```css
.none {
  display: none;
}

.block {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<ul class="one">
  <li class="two">
    <div class="three none">123</div>
  </li>
  <li class="two">
    <div class="three none">234</div>
  </li>
  <li class="two">
    <div class="three none">345</div>
  </li>
  <li class="two">
    <div class="three none">456</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: а как сделать чтоб при отведения мышки от тега див пропадал, такое возможно?

Comment: @IvanDurbala нужно использовать событие `mouseout`, добавил в ответ

Comment: спасибо большое, я просто js еще не учил, но дальше по курсу не могу продвинуться пока это не сделаю по требованием, хотя обычные модальные окна и тд сделал сам на простом js)

Comment: @IvanDurbala если ответ вас устраивает, то можете закрыть вопрос, нажав слева от ответа галочку. Удачи в изучении)